# get all emails of a Facebook user via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

when accessing email of a facebook user via facebook API I am only getting their primary email address. I want to get all of their email addresses. For most people primary email address is their college email address which they no longer user. Here is a screenshot of Facebook API description on this: http://screencast.com/t/pZT9xQ7AVEX. Any ideas?

Comment: it's not possible because it is much private data what i think
please refer http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ for what permissions are provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API will not provide you with a different email address.

The primary email is the email the user has selected as the one that they want used. So use that one.

Answer (score 0):

The API only provides the primary email address as you have experienced. I wouldn't necessarily assume that "all primary emails are college emails that aren't used anymore", unless you have a very specific demographic in your segmentation range. given Facebook is so "sticky", and that the younger users message via FB rather than email, you might need to revisit your assumptions and needs.

Ultimately, the most effective and most ethical way to access current and valid emails is to initiate some end user engagement activity to get them to supply it.